# Alternative way of implementation of a code

Tags: c#, .net

The title is not exactly meaningful, but I am not share what else to name it. I wrote a [TOC Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212590/feedback-on-toc-generation-code) code sometime later. Based on this I was writing code to check for duplicates also. The code is as follows

```
curNumber = getTOCReference(selItem.SNo, IsParent);
CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent,out realTOCRef);
curNumber = realTOCRef;
```

And the code for CheckForDuplicates is

```
        ListViewItem curItem = this.tlvItems.FindItemWithText(curNumber);

        if (curItem != null)
        {
            curNumber = this.getTOCReference(curNumber, !IsParent);
            CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent,out realTOCRef);
        }
        else
        {
            realTOCRef= curNumber;
        }
```

What this code does, it gets a TOC and tries it find if it already exists in the [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) and gets a new TOC if there is a existing TOC. Once it determines that the generated TOC is not there in the list it stores it in realTOCRef and sends it back to the main calling code.

I have used "out" to return the last generated TOC, which is something I did not want to do. The reason why I did it was after the non duplicate TOC was generated the return was not going back to the calling code instead it looped through the previous instances then it returned back. When the looping back happened the TOC that was to be returned also got reset.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The question is not that clear. I hope you are looking to refactor the CheckForDuplicates code and make a call as follows.
--------------
Existing :
CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent,out realTOCRef);
curNumber = realTOCRef;

-----------
Required: 
curNumber =CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a single out parameter, it can often be removed by using that value as the return value for the method. Replacing the out param, with the return value looks like this:

```
String CheckForDuplicates(String curNumber, bool IsParent) 
{
    ListViewItem curItem = this.tlvItems.FindItemWithText(curNumber);

    if (curItem != null)
    {
        String newNumber = this.getTOCReference(curNumber, !IsParent);
        curNumber = CheckForDuplicates(newNumber, IsParent);
    }
    // else - curNumber is correct - not a duplicate
    return curNumber;
}
```

As to design, I feel this code should be part of your `getTOCReference` so that clients don't have to worry about deduplication - it makes sense to make deduplication part of the basic function of `getTOCReference`. Its nothing complex - just a little renaming and some glue:

- rename `getTOCReference` to `getNextTOCReference` since that's really what it does - finds the TOC value that would come next, without checking for duplicates.
- create a new method `GetNextAvailableTOCRefernece`. To me `GetTOCRefernece` implies retreiving some kind of saved state and that multiple calls would return the same value. That's not what it does, so the new name makes it clear. It looks like this:

(essentially the code you gave at the top of the page, refactored to use return value, wrapped in a method.)

```
String GetNextAvailableTOCReference(String curNumber, bool IsParent) 
{
   String newNumber = GetNextTOCRefrence(curNumber, IsParent);
   return CheckForDuplicates(newNumber, IsParent);   
}
```

With these changes, you call `getNextAvailalbeTOCreference` when you need a new reference and you can be sure it is unique (no duplicates.)

I've left the code-style as is - I agree you could be a little more consistent, and provide comments for some of the logic - particularly `getTOCReference` since that does 4 different things depending upon method arguments. And of course, unit tests so that you can be sure it does what you say it does!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you looking for.

What I assume is that you are looking fore something like following.

Existing call:

```
CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent,out realTOCRef);
curNumber = realTOCRef;
```

Required call:

```
curNumber =CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent);
```

If yes, simple change the code to following it will work.

```
        ListViewItem curItem = this.tlvItems.FindItemWithText(curNumber);

        if (curItem != null)
        {
            curNumber = this.getTOCReference(curNumber, !IsParent);
            return  CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent);
        }
        else
        {
            return curNumber;
        }
```

Comment: that did not work. Probably because of the same issue. What is happening is if the loop is running for once we have one copy curNumber and more than loop it is creating a separate copy for each loop and when the first return is encountered it goes back to the old copy of curNumber and returns that copy. Well i guess that is what is happening in my knowledge. Thanks for the reply sachin :)

Comment: is the first part correct what i have assumed that you are looking for a function which will be 

curNumber =CheckForDuplicates(curNumber, IsParent);

Comment: I wanted the curNumber which was allocated in the last looping to be returned. In this case it was not. mdma has the right answer. Time to refactor the code.